# Can I change my CPU on a Quanta 3603 motherboard?

Tags: cpu, motherboard

[Here's my motherboard's specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vg6eR.png)

If I can change CPUs, kindly list the supported CPUs on this motherboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Quanta 3603" seems to be a motherboard of HP Pavilion dv5. I've found [this support question](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/RAM-upgrade-for-dv5-MB-Quanta-3603/td-p/7000259) which links to [maintenance manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01550108) for this laptop. Supported processors are listed on page 102:

- AMD Turion Ultra Dual-Core 35W ZM-86 2.40-GHz processor with 2-MB L2 cache
- AMD Turion Ultra Dual-Core 35W ZM-82 2.20-GHz, processor with 2-MB L2 cache
- AMD Turion Ultra Dual-Core 35W ZM-80 2.10-GHz, processor with 2-MB L2 cache
- AMD Turion Dual-Core 35W RM-70 2.00-GHz with 1-MB L2 cache processor
- AMD Athlon X2 Dual-Core 35W QL-60 1.90-GHz with 1-MB L2 cache processor
- Intel Core2 Duo T9600 2.80-GHz processor with 6-MB L2 cache and 1066-MHz FSB
- Intel Core2 Duo T9400 2.53-GHz processor with 6-MB L2 cache and 1066-MHz FSB
- Intel Core Duo T8600 2.40-GHz processor with 3-MB L2 cache and 1066-MHz FSB
- Intel Core Duo T8400 2.26-GHz processor with 3-MB L2 cache and 1066-MHz FSB

Please note that you can't switch from AMD to Intel or vice versa, their sockets are incompatible.